# Xaml - The name is already defined in this scope

Tags: c#, xaml, scope

I have defined a "Toggle" textblock inside three buttons. I am getting an error that the name "Toggle" Is already defined in the innermost scope of the second and third buttons.

Shouldn't they not be defined in the same scope? It seems they are...

If this is not the way to do it, how can one simply define similar items (Similar to how there can be an id property in css) so one can access the inside of each button via one same identifier in the code behind?

```
<Button Name="OutputButton" Margin="5" Width="150" Click="OutputToggle_Click" TabIndex="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock Name="OutputText" HorizontalAlignment="Center">RF 
        <TextBlock Name="Toggle" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBlock>
    </TextBlock>
</Button>
<Button Name="ModulationButton" Margin="5" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="ModulationToggle_Click" IsEnabled="False" TabIndex="0">
    <TextBlock Name="ModulationToggleText" Margin="3">Load Waveform to enable MOD
        <TextBlock Name="Toggle"></TextBlock>
    </TextBlock>
</Button>
<Button Name="LOSharingButton" Margin="5" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="AutomaticLOSharingButton_Click">
    <TextBlock Name="LOSharingText">LO Sharing
        <TextBlock Name="Toggle"></TextBlock>
    </TextBlock>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is to use the `tag` property of a textblock. This is very similar to the id property in css, but takes a little more effort to find.